# Writing file in CGI results in different file

Tags: perl, cgi

I have this part of code in Perl CGI:

```
open(FH, '>', '/tmp/homeip.conf') or die $!;
print FH $ip;
close FH;
```

But the file is written to `/tmp/systemd-private-CxvLw6/tmp/homeip.conf` instead of `/tmp/homeip.conf`. Why is this? and how can I write file to the desired folder?

Comment: Looks like your CGi process runs in a [chroot jail](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroot)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is this?

Applications shouldn't use `/tmp` because it is generally world-writable, which is a security risk. [systemd](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/) tries to fix that by [allowing services to create a private `/tmp` directory](https://securityblog.redhat.com/2014/04/09/new-red-hat-enterprise-linux-7-security-feature-privatetmp/) that is different from the `/tmp` that other users and services see.

This is enabled in Apache's systemd unit file (`/usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service` on my system):

```
[Unit]
Description=The Apache HTTP Server
After=network.target remote-fs.target nss-lookup.target

[Service]
...
PrivateTmp=true
```

---

> how can I write file to the desired folder?

It's a security risk, so just don't. If you need your temporary files to be accessible by other processes, store them in a directory that's not world-writable.